# Remove items from the Cluster Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markers, items

I have a clusterManager that contain items, and I want to remove these items every time that new items load. But what I get, is every time new items load, they're added to the previous ones. This happens even if I call these three lines:

```
mGoogleMap.clear();
mClusterManager.clearItems();
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

So what I want to achieve is to remove completely the previous items from my ClusterManager. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use `>` for emphasis. This should only be used for quoting.

Comment: @Naima, did you find cause or solution to your problem?

Comment: yes, I did , i found the solution the last year.